# how to add GAPlugin to my phone gap android project without plugman?

Tags: cordova

I had created a phone gap android project long back. now i want to add google analytics to my app. i created my projects manually not by using cordova command line.I know that to add plugins using plugman method we need to setup our project using command line. Please suggest a way to add google analytics plugin manually

[This is the plugin link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin)

i was build my project with phonegap 2.9

Comment: Please provide a link to the analytics plugin you are looking at, as well as what version of cordova/phonegap that you used to build the project initially.

Comment: @MBillau:Thank for your response. I had updated my question with required info